# Convert string to URL by removing "\"

Tags: ios, swift, url

I want to remove the `\"` from the begining and the end of the particular string to get the actual `URL`

**Code:** `let = subString = originalString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\", with: "")`

> "\"https://api.example.com/deep-link?url=some_url_encoded_string\""

What I want is:

> "https://api.example.com/deep-link?url=some_url_encoded_string"

Comment: Which version of Swift are you using?

Comment: Are you sure the String begins with `\"`? Asking because `\"` is an escape sequence for the `"` character, so your url might be surrounded by `"` instead.

Comment: Just trim the `\` character

Answer (score 3):

You could trim the string in order to remove all the leading and trailing quote symbols:

```swift
let url = "\"https://some-server/some/path\""
let processedString = str.trimmingCharacters(in: .init(charactersIn: "\""))
print(processedString) // https://some-server/some/path
```

Note that `\"` is not a string made of two characters, but an escape sequence for the quote symbol.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove `\"` wherever it is occurred in the string then use this:

```
let subString = originalString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "")
```

if you want to remove it just in the beginning and the end of the string then you will check:

```
if originalString.first == "\"" {
    _ = originalString.removeFirst()
}
if originalString.last == "\"" {
    _ = originalString.popLast() 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove character ".

like that.

```
let myString = "\"https://api.example.com/deep-link?url=some_url_encoded_string\"" 

let newString = myString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\", with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: """, with: "")

print(newString)
```

Comment: This will remove all `\\` from the URL, which will lead to an incorrect URL

Answer (score 0):

This backslash is here just because you need double quotes in string which otherwise wouldn't be possible in string declared on one line in Swift 4.2 or earlier.

---

In Swift 5 you could use raw string literals

```
let originalString = #""https...""#
```

---

So you actually need to remove just the only characters which are actually in string and they're double quotes (simplified: `\"` = `"`).

To do this you have to again use backslash before double quote `"\"` -> `"\""`

```
let subString = originalString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "")
```

Answer (score 0):

> Check below code

```
let originalString = "\"https://api.example.com/deep-link?url=some_url_encoded_string\""

var temp = "\("\"")" as? String

if originalString.hasPrefix(temp!){
    originalString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "")
}
```